# Can the C# compiler throw an error or warning if a certain method is called in a loop

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Often times a developer on my team writes code in a loop that makes a call that is relatively slow (i.e. database access or web service call or other slow method). This is a super common mistake.

Yes, we practice code reviews, and we try to catch these and fix them before merging. However, failing early is better, right?

So is there a way to catch this mistake via the compiler?

Example:

Imagine this method

```
public ReturnObject SlowMethod(Something thing) 
{
    // method work
}
```

Below the method is called in a loop, which is a mistake.

```
public ReturnObject Call(IEnumerable<Something> things)
{
    foreach(var thing in Things)
        SlowMethod(thing); // Should throw compiler error or warning in a loop
}
```

Is there any way to decorate the above SlowMethod() with an attribute or compiler statement so that it would complain if used in a loop?

Comment: The compiler compiles and has no idea how long your function might take. You probably need some post- action like Fody, to patch your assembly (and insert the timing check) after it is compiled.

Comment: @SGKoishi I don't expect the compiler to know it is slow. I expect to be able to add an attribute such as [DoNotRunInLoops] and then the compiler would only need to detect that the call was in a loop. Also, would be nice if a method calls a method [DoNotRunInLoops], then it should also have the same decoration.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing in regular C# to prevent a method being used in a loop.

Your options:

- discourage usage in a loop by providing easier to use alternatives. Providing second (or only) method that deals with collections will likely discourage one from writing calls in a loop enough so it is no longer a major concern.
- try to write your own code analysis rule (stating tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)
- add run-time protection to the method if it is called more often than you'd like.

Comment: I'll have to give writing my own analyzer a look. I think this is one analysis that is small, and yet would have a big benefit for the entire C# development community.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it makes sense to invoke those slow methods in a loop - you're trying to put work into preventing that, but that's putting work into something fundamentally negative. Why not do something positive instead? Obviously, you've provided an API that's convenient to use in a loop. So, provide some alternatives that are easier to use *correctly* where formerly an incorrect use in a loop would take place, like:

1. an iterable-based API that would make the loop implicit, to remove some of the latency since you'd have a full view of what will be iterated, and can hide the latency appropriately,
2. an async API that won't block the thread, with example code showing how to use it in the typical situations you've encountered thus far; remember that an API that's too hard to use correctly won't get used!
3. a lowest-common-denominator API: split the methods into a requester and a result provider, so that there'd naturally be two loops: one to submit all the requests, another to collect and process the results (I dislike this approach, since it doesn't make the code any nicer)

Comment: Your third point should never never stop your from doing it. You do it because you need it. When you don't need it, then you can simply neglect it where "it" can be any kind of heavy and ugly implementation. I do not mean bad code, that you should avoid at any time. :)

Comment: I’m at an age where I can afford some beauty in the implementation. Of course not everyone has that freedom, and many corporate environments are not conducive to it either.